# “"Welcome to the fourth episode of…” How many episodes have been done?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tenses

There is currently a debate among my friends. It is about our final listening test. In the audio script, the content was about a Radio show and the MC said

> "Welcome to the fourth episode of *Getting The Message Across*".

The question asked

"How many episodes have been done?" so I assumed 3 was done. But the correct answer was C. four.

I would like to hear your opinions about this as native English speakers.

Thank you[image]

Comment: You're on the 4th, then only  3 have been completed. The 4th isn't done yet.

Comment: The question, if one was being picky, should have asked: "How many episodes have been aired/broadcast?" Typically a production will have completed all the episodes *before* broadcasting the series to the general public.

Comment: I guess what the question implies is that if you are listening to the 4th episode, at least 4 have been *done*. The problem as I see it is whether the broadcast (picking on @Mari-LouA correct suggestion) is *live* or recorded. The *done* might be trying to imply that they have been recorded

Comment: When we hear the test, the speaker in the CD said "you will now hear a radio show..." then it start off just like any radio show

Comment: Depends on how you define "done".

Comment: Here's a question then: @HuyNguyễn, did you have to answer the questions *during* the broadcast, or *after*?

Comment: I didn't know for sure honestly. There wasn't any instruction whether we have to answer during or after the speech. We usually listen, read the questions and answer them at the same time. Fyi, we were listen to the end of the broadcast.

Comment: @microenzo Good point. I assumed the decision point was just after the introduction. If it was after the completion of the radio show, “4” becomes a/another valid answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about logic, not language. The OP clearly understands the language aspects.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was asked on EL&U (which assumes an audience proficient in English), this answer skips the ‘Exam English’ analysis and just deals with the core of the problem.

The real question behind the quote is what the author meant by *done*.

- *previously broadcast in their entirety*: three. The fourth hasn’t quite started properly yet and is certainly not *done* in this sense.
- *recorded* or *completed*: unknown. At the time the speaker recorded the words in the quote, three (the fourth hadn’t been completed). If the broadcast was live, it’s again three for the same reason. If the broadcast was from a recording, at least four. They could have recorded a hundred episodes and happened to be playing Episode 4.

So the answer is that it is indeterminate. All we can say without further information is that it is more than two.

Comment: With reference to the test: if one has to assume that the number is known, pick the scenarios associated with a fixed number. All those scenarios have three episodes. If one claims “four”, the same logic could be used to claim any higher number. I might have missed something, but I reckon the author didn’t think the question through properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will quote your opinion to my english teacher right away.